# Monitor directory recursively for file additions/modifications/deletions

Tags: freebsd, kqueue

I need to watch a directory with several subdirectories, each of which has files which I need to monitor for file additions, modifications and deletions.

I found some example code, and had to modify it slightly to get it working, but it doesn't exactly do what I need.  It can find a file rename, or delete within a directory (but not a subdirectory), but doesn't respond to file modifications.

The way that I can find using a Google search is to monitor each file individually; however, I have several hundreds of thousands of files to monitor, and holding a file descriptor to each is probably unwise.

Is there a way under FreeBSD to do what I need to do?  Or will I have to find an alternative solution?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) {
   int f, kq, nev;
   struct kevent change;
   struct kevent event;

   kq = kqueue();
   if (kq == -1)
       perror("kqueue");

   f = open("/tmp/foo", O_RDONLY);
   if (f == -1)
       perror("open");

   EV_SET(&change, f, EVFILT_VNODE,
          EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE | EV_ONESHOT,
          NOTE_DELETE | NOTE_EXTEND | NOTE_WRITE | NOTE_ATTRIB,
          0, 0);

   for (;;) {
       nev = kevent(kq, &change, 1, &event, 1, NULL);
       if (nev == -1)
           perror("kevent");
       else if (nev > 0) {
           if (event.fflags & NOTE_DELETE) {
               printf("File deleted\n");
               break;
           }
           if (event.fflags & NOTE_EXTEND ||
               event.fflags & NOTE_WRITE)
               printf("File modified\n");
           if (event.fflags & NOTE_ATTRIB)
               printf("File attributes modified\n");
       }
   }

   close(kq);
   close(f);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly guessed, `kqueue` is not scalable because you have to hold a handle to the file / directory in question, even if in `O_RDONLY` mode. On Linux, one would use `inotify` for this purpose (http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), but I believe there is no FreeBSD port of this kernel feature!

If you have the time and resources, what you could do is look at the code for `audit` on BSD (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=audit&sektion=4) and try to code up a version of inotify for BSD! O_O

Comment: I don't think this'd be any easier with inotify. Inotify isn't recursive either, you'd still have monitor each file inidividually. The audit framework is a good suggestion though. Perhaps even dtrace might be useful here.

Comment: Do you know if usage of `audit` would require opening `fd`s to each monitored file.  Also at @KristofProvost, I didn't know it wasn't recursive, if a recursive solution is required, that's cool.  The major problem is holding all of those file descriptors.

Comment: Also Merry Christmas. :D

Comment: Merry Christmas, too! (But then you are an OmnipotentEntity, so maybe I should say : "Thank you for Christmas!"? :-) ).

Comment: I'm 90% sure that the auditing mechanism does not require opening fds because it basically works inside the kernel (mostly) and logs syscalls. For example, if someone calls chmod() on a file that you are monitoring, the kernel code of chmod() itself does the logging. I suppose the real questions now are: a) how resource-intensive is it? and b) how easy is it to setup recursive directory monitoring? Let me know if you want me to dig up / help.

Comment: Just thanks so much for the pointer.  I'll look into it.  If I develop anything nice I'll throw it on github or something.